# How can I make a LauchScreen in XCode with Swift, with animation?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, screen, loading

In XCode, how can I make a LauchScreen, that moves a square after 45% loading. Delaying is not the best, because launch times differ by memory usage, phone model, etc.

So after loading 45% of the app, the next 10% animates a square into the center of the screen.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

It would be a table game with 9( 3^2 ) places to place your coins on. The loading screen is the bottom and the middle row are in place, but the top row only has 2 squares on start, pushed to the right. As the loading process progresses, the squares move to the left. Upon finishing the loading, the same screen remains with the menu on the bottom displaying, but that's just a tab bar.

Comment: Please share some info on your app logic, mainly on what are you loading and how is your app started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, the loading screen is static, even if you use Nib or storyboard.

The only thing you can do is start your app as fast as possible, by only loading a simple screen and displaying it right after your app is started.
Then load the more complex part of your app and remove this loading screen once your app has completely started.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html), the Launch Screen is there to give the impression of quick loading.

> Design a plain launch image that improves the user experience. In particular, the launch image isn’t an opportunity to provide:
>
> An “app entry experience,” such as a splash screen
>
> An About window
>
> Branding elements, unless they are a static part of your app’s first screen

If you want something animated when the app launches, create a custom class, but keep in mind:

> Because users are likely to switch among apps frequently, you should make every effort to cut launch time to a minimum, and you should design a launch image that downplays the experience rather than drawing attention to it.

Edit: I missed your edit, and understand your intentions!